# How can I use map on the resulting list of another function?

Tags: haskell

```
mean :: (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
mean xs = (realToFrac(sum xs) / realToFrac(length xs))

sqDiff1 :: (Fractional b, Real b) => [b] -> [b]
sqDiff1 xs = map(subtract (mean xs))xs
sqDiff2 :: Num b => (t -> [b]) -> t -> [b]
sqDiff2 sqDiff2 xs = map(^ 2)(sqDiff2 xs)
```

sqDiff1 subtracts the mean of a list from each of the elements.

Basically what I'm trying to do is square the elements of sqDiff1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Omg, `sqDiff2` is ambiguous... :(

Comment: And what's your problem? Any error message?

Comment: do you want this: map (^2) (sqDiff1 xs)? The type signature of sqDiff2 have to modify as: sqDiff2::Real b=>[b]->[b]

Comment: Naming a function's parameter the same as that function is very confusing, and will be even worse if you try to recurse.

Comment: @DannyuNDos It's not ambiguous, though I can see how it might be confusing. `sqDiff2` in the body of the function refers to the named parameter, which shadows the name of the function. It's very well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to square the differences from only that function, you don't need a function parameter:

```
sqDiff2 :: Real b => [b] -> [b]
sqDiff2 xs = map (^ 2) (sqDiff1 xs)
```

If you really intended to have a function parameter, pass the one you want to use:

```
*Main> sqDiff2 sqDiff1 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[6.25,2.25,0.25,0.25,2.25,6.25]
```